# backbone.js: how to send constraints when doing a list GET

Tags: backbone.js

I'm trying to build an application using backbone.js and backbone-relational.js on the frontend, with a RESTful api run by Pyramid/Cornice/SQLAlchmeny on the backend.

At this stage, I have two models, Client (basically businesses) and Asset (the assets that the businesses own) ... and eventually there will be a number of other models, for users, sites, etc. A simplified example of the two models:

```
Client:
  id
  name

Asset:
  id
  make
  model
  purchase_cost
  client_id
```

Now, my backbone.js code is currently working fine when fetching the data from these models from the server; I have two list views, one that shows a list of all the clients, and another that shows a list of all the assets.

My problem now is that I when I click on one of the Clients, in the list of clients, I want it to then show a list of only the Assets that belong to that particular client. No problem with the server-side part of that, it's just a filter(), my question is, how do I make backbone.js send such a constraint when it requests the list of Assets?

(While I've used RelationalModel in the code below, I'm still learning it and haven't really worked out how to make use of it yet)

```
window.Asset = Backbone.RelationalModel.extend({
    urlRoot:"/api/assets",
    defaults:{
        "id":null,
        "make":null,
        "model":null,
        "purchase_cost":null,
    },
    relations: [{
        type: Backbone.HasOne,
        type: Backbone.HasOne,
        key: 'client_id',
        relatedModel: Client
    }]
});

window.AssetCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Asset,
    url: "/api/assets"
});

window.Client = Backbone.RelationalModel.extend({
    urlRoot:"/api/clients",
    defaults:{
        "id":null,
        "name":null
    }
});

window.ClientCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Client,
    url: "/api/clients"
});
```

I don't think I need to show any of the Views here.

In my router, I currently have a listClients function and a listAssets (see below) function, and I think I'll need to add a listAssetsforClient(clientid) function, but I'm not sure what I'm meant to do with the clientid so that backbone.js will send it to the server as a constraint when GETting the list of Assets. I presume that whatever needs to be done will be in the AssetCollection model, but I can't see anything in the Collection API that looks appropriate. There are methods that will do filtering on an already fetched list, but it seems inefficient to be fetching an entire list of assets (and there may eventually be thousands of them) when I only need a subset of them, and can get the server to filter instead.

```
listAssets: function() {
    $('#header').html(new AssetHeaderView().render().el);
    this.assetList = new AssetCollection();
    var self = this;
    this.assetList.fetch({
        success:function () {
            self.assetListView = new AssetListView({model:self.assetList});
            $('#sidebar').html(self.assetListView.render().el);
            if (self.requestedId) self.assetDetails(self.requestedId);
        }
    });
},
```

Comment: I think that instead of $('#header').html(new AssetHeaderView().render().el); you should use $('#header').append(new AssetHeaderView().render().$el); But maybe I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have figured it out. The fetch() method has an optional 'data' parameter which can pass the constraint. So, my new function would be:

```
listAssetsforClient: function(id) {
    $('#header').html(new AssetHeaderView().render().el);
    this.assetList = new AssetCollection();
    var self = this;
    this.assetList.fetch({
        data: { clientid: id },
        success:function () {
            self.assetListView = new AssetListView({model:self.assetList});
            $('#sidebar').html(self.assetListView.render().el);
            if (self.requestedId) self.assetDetails(self.requestedId);
        }
    });
},
```

Comment: Of course, this only works for getting the data, and now I have to figure out how to get the clientid when saving a new asset object...